# OpenCV Perspective corrention and cropping

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv

I'm currently trying to correct the perspective of a random taken image showing a rectangle.

The perspective correction is working fine, but i want to crop the image to the target, too. Si I've tried to transform the given contour of my target by the perspective matrix (`cv::Mat`) and crop it with the results.

My method is currently crashing at the marked line with the following error.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mtype == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(mtype) == CV_MAT_CN(type0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0)) in create, file /Volumes/build-storage/build/master_iOS-mac/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 2430
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Volumes/build-storage/build/master_iOS-mac/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:2430: error: (-215) mtype == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(mtype) == CV_MAT_CN(type0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0) in function create
```

Code

```
cv::Mat correctMat(cv::Mat mat, std::vector<cv::Point> contour) {
    double minObjectSize = 100.0;

    if (contour.size() == 4) {
        cv::Rect rect = cv::boundingRect(contour);

        if (rect.height < minObjectSize || rect.width < minObjectSize) {
            NSLog(@"Objects size was too small: %d * %d", rect.width, rect.height);
        }
        else {
            std::vector<Point2f> quad_pts;
            std::vector<Point2f> squre_pts;

            quad_pts.push_back(Point2f(contour[0].x, contour[0].y));
            quad_pts.push_back(Point2f(contour[1].x, contour[1].y));
            quad_pts.push_back(Point2f(contour[3].x, contour[3].y));
            quad_pts.push_back(Point2f(contour[2].x, contour[2].y));

            squre_pts.push_back(Point2f(rect.x, rect.y));
            squre_pts.push_back(Point2f(rect.x, rect.y + rect.height));
            squre_pts.push_back(Point2f(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y));
            squre_pts.push_back(Point2f(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height));

            Mat transmtx = getPerspectiveTransform(quad_pts, squre_pts);
            Mat transformed = Mat::zeros(mat.rows, mat.cols, CV_8UC3);

            cv::line(mat, quad_pts[0], quad_pts[1], Scalar(0,0,255), 5, CV_AA, 0);
            cv::line(mat, quad_pts[1], quad_pts[2], Scalar(0,0,255), 5, CV_AA, 0);
            cv::line(mat, quad_pts[2], quad_pts[3], Scalar(0,0,255), 5, CV_AA, 0);
            cv::line(mat, quad_pts[3], quad_pts[0], Scalar(0,0,255), 5, CV_AA, 0);

            warpPerspective(mat, transformed, transmtx, mat.size());

            std::vector<cv::Point2f> transformedPoints;

            cv::Matx23f matrix = *transmtx.clone().ptr();

            cv::transform(quad_pts, transformedPoints, matrix);

            cv::Mat cropped = transformed(cv::boundingRect(transformedPoints));

            fixColorOfMat(cropped);

            return cropped;
        }
    }

    return mat;
}
```

I do not really know what the error message is telling me so i hope somebody here could help me solving this crash.

**Next Problem**

I've changed the code a bit, the transform action on the point vector works now, but i'm unabled to crop the Mat by these transformed points.

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> transformedPoints;

cv::Matx23f matrix = *transmtx.clone().ptr();

cv::transform(quad_pts, transformedPoints, matrix);

// Crash
cv::Mat cropped = transformed(cv::boundingRect(transformedPoints));
```

The error message says

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat, file /Volumes/build-storage/build/master_iOS-mac/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 522
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Volumes/build-storage/build/master_iOS-mac/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:522: error: (-215) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows in function Mat
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I used `memcpy()` convert vector to Mat directly. Maybe you can try that on the transform part.

```
 memcpy(Mat.data, vector.data(), vector.size()*sizeof(Point));
```

As long as you got the mask matrix of contour, I think you can use `bitwise()` to corp your target result.

Btw, I cannot explain opencv's error statement, as I have never understood it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm got the transformation on the point-vector working now, but cropping the image fails now. I've added the new error too.

Comment: I could not solve anymore cuz I am not familiar with 3d perspective stuff. However, I could not check any information about `transformed()`. But what I found is in transform, when the `matrix.cols==quad_pts.channels()`, `dst(I) = m.src(I)`. otherwise, `dst(I) = m.[src(I); 1]`. So, I think you can check the matrix column and input matrix channel number first maybe. And it should help you solved the error.